# Central limit theorem specification

Tags: mathematical-statistics, central-limit-theorem

My question is rather simple. Clt seems to apply to finite and unknown populations. What if the population is not finite? Inferring the approximation to normality of sample means of volume of sales samples for instance.. Would the Clt still apply if the population is evolving endlessly?

Comment: What do you mean by "Clt seems to apply to finite and unknown populations"?

Comment: I mean that you want to establish the approximation to normality of the sample mean distribution of a population that is finite, like the voters in a political elections, the outcome of coin toss trials having just two outcomes (head or tail).. What if my inference is meant to a continuous distribution that is always evolving? How can clt establish normality of sample mean distribution of data streaming whose ultimate population will never be known, like sales or net gaming revenues or similar?

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen a formulation of the CLT that applies only to finite populations.  They are *all* in terms of *distributions* of random variables, not populations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLT applies to continuous distributions (e.g., trivially for sampling from a normal distribution). One requirement for CLT is that the population is [stationary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) so that it even makes sense to talk of, say, the mean of the population. (Technical note: you can actually have a degree of non-stationarity as specified by the [Lindeberg Condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) and still achieve convergence — yet the question remains if the resulting normal distribution is relevant to your question)

If the underlying characteristics of your sample space are changing then you are dealing with a non-stationary population. In this case, does it even make sense to ask about *the* population mean?

Normally, you’ll need to account for the evolution of the system using the tools of time series analysis — de-trend, remove periodic/cyclical behavior, etc so that you are back to sampling from a stationary distribution and have firmer ground to interpret your results.

Comment: Thank you Bey. That makes sense